# How to correctly set the XDG base dirs gobally and dynamically

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, profile, base-dir-spec

I get a lot of config folders in my home folder. I assume that is, because `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is not set and some software (e.g. fontconfig, umlet) does not follow the standards.

> `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` defines the base directory relative to which user
> specific configuration files should be stored. If `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is
> either not set or empty, a default equal to `$HOME/.config` should be
> used.

Now since my distribution does not set it, I want to do it. Most of the internet comments recommend to write it in the `.bashrc`. But I am the system administrator and want to do this for all users including future users, without introducing future maintenance work.

This means I want to set it system-wide (globally) and since every new users should inherit it, it should be dynamically, using e.g. `$HOME/.config`.

How can I solve this general problem in a reasonable way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insted of `.bashrc` put the setting line to `/etc/profile`. This file is loaded on every user login just like `.bashrc` is for a specific user. The bonus is this works for other shells and sessions as well.

Comment: Will `$HOME` be correctly expanded in `/etc/profile`?

Comment: Should be, it is supposed to be executed by the login shell in the same fashion as .bashrc & friends.